# Image background in OpenCart

Tags: php, html, css, opencart

I develop a eCommerce site with the help of OpenCart CMS. I want to set an image as background at the home page.

If I want to put an image as background of a table in OpenCart, then what to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in "catalog/view/theme/yourtheme/stylesheet/stylesheet.css"

```
body {
background: #ffffff url('../image/your_background.jpg');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can find the answer here: http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?t=75679